# add data in in-memory database using Java Classes?

Tags: java, in-memory-database, jhipster

I am working on **jhipster Release 0.7.0** and i want to add data in in-memory database.

There is a way to add data using `CSV file`.

But i need to do it using java so is there any other option to add data in database by using `java classes` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "normal" way to do it is using Liquibase, using the files in your /src/main/resources/config/liquibase directory.

If you want to do it directly in Java, the easiest way would be to use JPA, using your JPA Repositories. Have a look at the methods provided by Spring Data JPA, if you call one of the sample repositories.

Comment: With Liquibase, it does it at startup time, this is provided by Spring Boot. You should see the Liquibase logs at the end of the start up.